# Locking and Terminating User Sessions via Group Policy settings

Tags: windows-7, security, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

To conform with some new security requirements, my company is implementing Group Policy solutions to existing security vulnerabilities. My current assignment is to *find and implement Group Policy settings that will cause the current user session to lock after a configured period of idle time and terminate an inactive user session after a given period of time*.

These settings are supposed to apply to all user sessions, local or remote, and are to be enacted in a domain environment (forest) containing a mixture of workstations and servers. I can't, for the life of me, figure out if I just glossed over some obscurely-placed setting, or if such settings even exist.

*The Cut-&-Dry* (*with arbitrary example numbers*): User sessions automatically locking after 30 minutes of inactivity. User sessions terminating after 180 minutes of inactivity. Applies to both local and remote user sessions. **Is this possible via Group Policy? If so, where are these settings?**

Related (but unanswered): [Auto lock the screen for any user after specified period of inactivity on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/768763/auto-lock-the-screen-for-any-user-after-specified-period-of-inactivity-on-window)

Comment: If my question needs to be split into multiple questions, please let me know via the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking a session (either local or remote) is done using the screen saver settings.
User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization:
Enable screen saver - Enabled
Force specific screen saver - Enabled
Password protect screen saver - Enabled
Screen saver timeout - Enabled

As far as I remember, you need to configure all four.
Also, this policies apply to Server 2008r2 and Win7 - I think XP has other settings.

As for terminating a session, it exists only for remote sessions.
User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Session Time Limits:
Set time limit for active but idle Remote Desktop Services sessions - Enabled
Set time limit for disconnected sessions - Enabled
Terminate session when time limits are reached - Enabled

If you want to do the same for local sessions, you'll need to script it.